# about the limit point of a sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I want to ask this question:

Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ the sequence of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ defined as:

$x_{n}=1$ if n even and $x_{n}=n$ if n is odd.

How to show that 1 is the unique limit point of the sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$?.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily show that $1$ is a limit point since there is subsequence (sequence of even terms) that converges to $1.$ To show it is the unique limit point, go by contradiction. Say there is another limit point $a$ not equal to $1$ then there must be a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ converging to that point. Now clearly the subsequence cannot have all odd terms in it since a sequence of only odd terms is not convergent. Thus it must have even terms also and therefore the difference $|a-1|<\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small for $\epsilon>0$ and thus $a=1.$

Comment: thank you sir for your help. it was a nice proof.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,we know that when we talk about limit point,surely we must have a set...
so in this case we want to show that 1 is a limit point of the set {x_n:n is natural}.
Also we know that a number p is a limit point of subset A of R if for each positive number c there is an element a in A s.t a belongs to the interval (p-c,p+c).
now, let c be a positive number,since 1 is in {x_n :n is natural} then 1 belongs to (1-c,1+c).
Then 1 is a limit point of this set

Answer (score 0):

we know that if $a$$\in A$ then $a$  is a limit point of $A$.
since $1$ $\in$ {$x_n$:$n$$\in N$}$=A$ (because $x_1$$=$$x_3$$=x_5$$=...=1$),therefore $1$ is a limit point of $A$